# Django Chartit Not Displaying

Tags: jquery, python, django, highcharts

I am using django 1.6 & python2.7

I am attempting to use chartit , but receiving no display .

I added chartit to install_apps in settings.py

I tried to dumb down my code as much as possible, still not loading

**urls.py**

```
url(r"^chart/$", "carriermgr.views.ChartLs"),
```

**Views.py**

```
def ChartLs(request, template_name='carrier/carrierchart.html'):
    thedata = \
    DataPool(
            series=
            [{'options': {
                    'source': CarrierSnapshot.objects.all()},
            'terms': [
                    'dbaname',
                    'VServiceUS',
                    'VSvcPercUS']}
             ])

    cht = Chart(
            datasource = thedata,
            series_options =
                    [{'options':{
                            'type': 'column',
                            'stacking': False},
                    'terms':{
                            'dbaname': [
                                    'VServiceUS',
                                    'VSvcPercUS']
                    }}],
            chart_options =
                    {'title': {
                            'text': 'Out of Service compared to National Average'},
                    'xAxis': {
                            'title': {
                                    'text': 'carrier'}}})
    return render_to_response(template_name, {'NATAVGchart':cht})
```

**carrierchart.html**

```
<html>
 <head>
<script src ="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src ="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
{% load chartit %}
{{ NATAVGchart|load_charts:"container"}}
</head>
<body>
<div id=”container”>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

During Inspect Element, i can see the correct data being loaded from the view. So i am assuming it is accessing the model fine.

**Inspect Element**

The page loads with no error. Jquery, Highchart,  and Chartloader are all loading.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _chartit_hco_array = [{"series": [{"stacking": false, "data": [0, 136], "type": "line", "name":     "Vserviceus"}, {"stacking": false, "data": [0.00, 6.00], "type": "line", "name": "Vsvcpercus"}], "yAxis":     [{"title": {"text": "Vserviceus & Vsvcpercus"}}], "chart": {"renderTo": "container"}, "xAxis": [{"categories":     ["carrier1", " carrier2"], "title": {"text": "carrier"}}], "title": {"text": "National Average"}}];
</script>
```

Any guidance appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: You need to include the `jquery.js` file **before** highcharts

Comment: Still returning blank screen.  

I am seeing a new item during inspect element... (i am on a different computer now, not sure if it is a version difference)

  

    `<object type="{0C55C096-0F1D-4F28-AAA2-85EF591126E7}"   cotype="cs" id="cosymantecbfw" style="width: 100%; height: 0px; display: block; position: absolute; z-index:99999; top:0px; left:0px;"></object>`

Comment: Do you receive any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the quotation marks in your id div from what you have to " ". You copied and pasted that is why you got those marks from Word or so.